# ESP32 - response not valid after http request

Tags: json, https, esp32

I'm trying to do an post request and then read out the response to process this.

The response I have is the following:
`{"version":"0.0.7"}`

Or that is what I have in Postman.

```cpp
// Check if the ESP it's version number is in need of an update
WiFiClientSecure checkForUpdateClient;
Serial.println(F("Checking for updates!"));
checkForUpdateClient.setInsecure();
if (!checkForUpdateClient.connect(DIGITAL_HQ_BASE_URL, 443)) {
    Serial.println(F("Connection failed"));
    return;
}
Serial.println(F("Connected!"));
StaticJsonDocument<64> doc;
doc["key"] = DEVICE_SECRET;
String updateData;
serializeJson(doc, updateData);
// Make a HTTP request:
checkForUpdateClient.print("POST "); // watch the space!
checkForUpdateClient.print(DIGITAL_HQ_VERSION_ENDPOINT); // API endpoint
checkForUpdateClient.println(" HTTP/1.1"); // watch the space!
checkForUpdateClient.print("Host: ");
checkForUpdateClient.println(DIGITAL_HQ_BASE_URL);
checkForUpdateClient.println("Connection: close");
checkForUpdateClient.print("User-Agent: ");
checkForUpdateClient.println(DIGITAL_HQ_USER_AGENT);
checkForUpdateClient.println("Content-Type: application/json");
checkForUpdateClient.print("Content-Length: ");
checkForUpdateClient.println(updateData.length());
checkForUpdateClient.println();
checkForUpdateClient.println(updateData);
checkForUpdateClient.println();
if (checkForUpdateClient.println() == 0) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to send request"));
    checkForUpdateClient.stop();
    return;
}
// Check HTTP status
char status[32] = {0};
checkForUpdateClient.readBytesUntil('\r', status, sizeof(status));
Serial.println("Status:");
Serial.println(status);
if (strcmp(status, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK") != 0) {
    Serial.print(F("Unexpected response: "));
    // Status can be used to filter out the response code
    Serial.println(status);
    checkForUpdateClient.stop();
    return;
}
// Skip HTTP headers
char endOfHeaders[] = "\r\n\r\n";
if (!checkForUpdateClient.find(endOfHeaders)) {
    Serial.println(F("Invalid response"));
    checkForUpdateClient.stop();
    return;
}
Serial.print("Building the JSON object with a capacity of ");
const size_t objCapacity = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(1) + 60; // overhead
DynamicJsonDocument otaResponse(objCapacity);
// Parse JSON object
DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(otaResponse, checkForUpdateClient)
if (error) {
    Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
    Serial.println(error.f_str());
    checkForUpdateClient.stop();
    return;
}
// Extract values
Serial.println(F("Response:"));
Serial.println(otaResponse.as<String>());
Serial.println(otaResponse["version"].as<String>());
if (otaResponse["version"].as<String>() > DIGITAL_HQ_SOFTWARE_VERSION) {
    // UPDATE
    Serial.println("System required update");
    doUpdate(); // Triggers the update sequence
} else {
    Serial.println("Device is up to date");
}
```

The problem is that I have the following responses (serial);

```
17:11:38.366 -> Checking for updates!
17:11:39.152 -> Connected!
17:11:39.841 -> Status:
17:11:39.874 -> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
17:11:39.874 -> Building the JSON object with a capacity of deserializeJson() failed: InvalidInput
```

Now I just need the response to be decoded by json then I need to be able to check it's value.

the problem is, the `checkForUpdateClient` is returning "1", but not the object. While I still have the exact same code for this url: `api.ipify.org/?format=json`, there it works just fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If I were going to debug this, the first thing I'd do is figure out what the "invalidInput" is by printing the content that the POST request returned. You're getting an error when you deserialize the JSON; why would you expect `checkForUpdateClient` to return an object?

Comment: I ligitimit have no idea how this works... I have a simmular piece of code which does work here: https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2109228
This code returns an IP address. I don't know what is different in that code...

Comment: Well, your first order of business is doing exactly romkey said. Print out what you got from the server before you feed it to the JSON parser. Here's a [sample](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFiClientSecure/examples/WiFiClientSecure/WiFiClientSecure.ino) of how it's done - see the last loop on lines 92-95

Comment: @Tarmo So I did and the connection fails after that. Now, I have seen that I get the correct response somehow, but it has an strange prefix and an weird suffix (lines) Like this: https://i.imgur.com/FJ2JD1B.png I have no idea why this is...

Comment: That's what your server sends. Can't comment on that, except I wouldn't expect a terminating zero inside an HTTP response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that I din't send a content-length header in the server API. Once I've added that, I could just use the code I wrote lol... Thanks to all for being my rubber ducky :s

Comment: without content-lenght the server sent the response body as HTTP chunked transfer encoded so it was not a valid JSON